# Error "Failed Signature verification" while attempting to update via CF10 Administrator

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfadmin

When you attempt to apply any hot fixes via the ColdFusion 10 Administrator you continuously get:

```
Error occurred while installing the update:
Failed Signature verification
```

You may have even validated the files and manually and placed them in the `hf-updates` directory at which point the CF10 admin page still shows the "Install" option, but again you receive the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error means you've forgotten to apply the [ColdFusion 10 Mandatory Update](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-mandatory-update.html) which updates the certificate used to validate install packages.

From Adobe's website:

> All ColdFusion updates are now signed with the new code signing
>   certificate because of a code signing certificate revocation. This
>   mandatory Update ensures that your current installation of ColdFusion
>   10 is updated with the new code signing certificate. This update is
>   also required for proper functioning of the auto update functionality
>   in ColdFusion 10. Adobe strongly recommends that you apply this
>   update.

Once the update has been installed ([you can find the JAR install instructions here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSe61e35da8d318518-33adffe0134c60cd31c-7ffe.html)) the service will be restarted and you will be able to apply subsequent updates via the ColdFusion administrator.

**Edit:**
Run the command prompt as Administrator:

[image]

Navigate to your jar file, and run the following command to run jar file:

```
D:\>java -jar cf10_mdt_updt.jar
```

Comment: What happens if you have installed the mandatory update and you still get this error?

Comment: @unclesol If you are trying to download update 12, download and install update 11 first.  You should then be able to download update 12 without getting the error.

Comment: I was getting an error as well from a fresh install with the mandatory update applied and updating to 11 prior to 12 was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

@UncleSol,

I also encountered the issue after having installed the mandatory update (cf10_mdt_updt.jar). After successfully applying the mandatory update, CF wanted to apply update 12 as the first update, which is where I encountered this issue, so I downloaded and manually installed Update 11 from this page:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-updates.html (installed in exactly the same manner as NotJustClarkKent's instructions)

After manually installing update 11, I was able to use the CF Updater to install the rest of my updates.

Hope that helps.